# Populating a Struct with a Binary file

Tags: c++, struct, binary, ifstream, seekg

I am attempting to read a binary file ("example.dat") in reverse and populating a struct of records with its contents. The file contains 10 records, and each record has three data types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/* Gross Yearly Income */
const unsigned long int GYI = sizeof( unsigned long int );

/* Amortization Period in years as an unsigned integer */
const unsigned int APY = sizeof( unsigned int );

/* Year ly interest rate in double precision */
const double annualInterest = sizeof( double );

/*This is where I attempt to determine the size of the file and most likely a huge fail. */

/* Attempting to obtain file size */
const int RECORD_SIZE = GYI + APY + annualInterest;

/* There are ten records*/
const int RECORDS = 10;

struct record_t
{    
    unsigned long int grossAnnualIncome;
    unsigned int amortizationPeriod;
    double interestRate;

} total[RECORDS]; // a total of ten records

void printrecord (record_t *record);

int main()
{   
    record_t *details = new record_t[RECORDS];

    ifstream file; /* mortgage file containing records */

    file.open( "mortgage.dat", ios::binary );

/*This for loop is an attempt to read the .dat file and store the values found into the relevant    struct*/

    for ( int i = 0; i < RECORDS; i++)
    {           
        file.seekg( -( i + 1 ) * RECORD_SIZE, file.end);
        file.read( ( char * )( &details[i].grossAnnualIncome ), GYI );
        file.read( ( char * )( &details[i].amortizationPeriod ), APY );
        file.read( ( char * )( &details[i].interestRate ), annualInterest );    

        cout << i << " : " ; printrecord(details);
    }

    file.close();       

    return 0;       
}    

/* Display the file records according to data type */

void printrecord (record_t *record)
{
    cout << record -> grossAnnualIncome << endl;
    cout << record -> amortizationPeriod << endl;
    cout << record -> interestRate << endl;
}
```

/* Any help and feedback is appreciated. */

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The output is always 

 749126312092639282,
1814962227,
1.26773e+213

for every record

Comment: Ignoring the fact you're always printing the first record, 1) you didn't provide how you wrote the file, and 2) whether you verified that the file you wrote contains correct data.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not write the file; which makes it difficult to verify its contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you get such strange number in for instance the interest-rate I cannot say I see. However, the reason you get the same values for every entry is because the line

```
cout << i << " : " ; printrecord(details);
```

Always prints the *first* entry in `details`. If you change it to:

```
cout << i << " : " ; printrecord(details + i);
```

It will print the actual values recorded into `details`.

---

The reason for this is that the identifier of an array will behave as a pointer to the first element of the array. Furthermore, you may do pointer-arithmetic on this pointer. Thus the following two statements are equivalent.

```
details + i
&details[i]
// This last one is just for fun, but is actually also equivalent to the other two.
&[i]details
```

Comment: I was able to retrieve the first two records by adding details + i to my source code. Much appreciated.

Comment: Wonderful, if you liked the answer, feel free to upvote or accept it. :)